# NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain.getRequestMatcher()

Tags: java, spring, security

I am trying to migrate from Spring 2 to 4 and am receiving this error.  Any help on how to handle this problem would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you are using Maven,ensure that you have right set of dependencies in it.

Comment: Spring or Spring Security? What are you trying to upgrade?

Comment: Could you tell us how exactly are you trying to migrate? What are the steps you are trying to follow?

Comment: I am upgrading to spring 4 including the security libraries.  The app is running on Wildfly.  I don't know why I'm receiving this error since the older version of Spring security has this same method with the same return type.